# call a javascript confirm dialog within php

Tags: javascript, php, confirm

I'm trying to call a javascript confirm dialog box inside my php script,this doesn't seem to work, am i doing something wrong, is the a better way do this, here's an example of the code:

```
<?php
   echo "<script language=\"javascript\">";
       echo "var answer = confirm(\"Are you sure you want to delete this Buyer?\")";
       echo "if (answer !=0) { ";
           $g->DelBuyer($reg);
       echo "}else{";
           echo" You preesed cancel";
       echo "}";
    echo "</script>";
enter code here
```

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.

Comment: PHP executes on the server. Javascript executes on the client. What you want is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for you to do this is use plain JavaScript when the user presses the button,

If you are afraid the user will disable JavaScript and then delete certain items, you could build in a fallback which would send you to another PHP page with a confirmation message.

Assuming you have the following button on the page:

```
<input type="submit" name="buttonName" value="Delete" onclick="confirm('http://www.yourdomain.com/path/item/deletion/url/');" />
```

In JavaScript you would create a function e.g.

```
function confirm(url) {

    var answer = confirm('your message');
    if (answer != 0)
        //Send the user to the correct page when he presses 'yes / oke'
        window.location.href = url;
    else
        alert('You cancelled the operation.');

    //Returns false so no events will be executed.
    return false;

}
```

This should do for what your question describes, if you need more info let me know.

‐ Sid